# What is the killer reason for using Mongoose ORM?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I've been using it with a new project, but it is also my first time using MongoDB. Defining a schema seems unnecessary because I thought the upside of mongo was that it didn't need defined schemes. Can't I just save objects on the fly no matter the schema? Then why would I want to? Also the documentation is lacking, making some things I can easily do in the mongo shell harder then they should be.

Comment: When calling MongoDB schemaless, it really refers to the fact that the database itself requires no schema and no schema migrations either.  That does not mean that your data is always unstructured - in most cases you want your data to be structured, and by nature, it usually is.

Comment: There are definitely cases where you want to migrate data.

Comment: @nbro - There was zero value editing this question, just to add line-breaks, *especially* since 1) it's 4 years old, and 2) under today's StackOverflow guidelines, this question is now off-topic as opinion-based. You didn't even take the time to edit out the preamble about a new project and first time using MongoDB (which is completely superfluous).

Comment: @DavidMakogon IMO, line-breaks help in general to make questions and answers more readable, if put properly. It could also be 10-years old, if IMO I think it needs to be edited to make it more readable, I will do it always, as far as they give me the permission to do it, and I have time to do it. You should thank me instead of claiming, but whatever, people are so ungrateful.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The best thing about Mongoose for MongoDB is the fact that you can have built-in automatic validation of the data which you are inserting/updating.  Mongoose also gives you the ability to pre-define events to happen, say, before a document gets saved.  This is very powerful because it consolidates the code you would have to write, and it places that code where it should be next to the document logic and not in the application logic.

Check out [middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) and validation for some examples.
alexyoung/Nodepad on Github has some good examples in the [models.js file](https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad/blob/master/models.js).

Answer (score 8):

Knowing a defined schema beforehand can be handy, because then you can make assumptions that you otherwise might not be able to.

For example, if I have a `Post` schema, then I can assume that it has a `body` field and use it as a `String` without checking its existence.

Granted, even on my well-defined model, I can have the equivalent of a schemaless document inside it, e.g.

```
mongoose.model('Post', new Schema({
    body: String,
    meta: {}
}));
```

and then I can very simply add random data to myPost.meta at whim. It provides a very nice balance for me between defined schema and schemaless.

Answer (score 3):

You can really go either way on it. There are many popular mappers for MongoDB in many other languages: Morphia for Java, Doctrine for PHP, Mongoid / Mongomapper for Ruby, etc.

Even though MongoDB is "schema-less" it's not "schema-free". There's something to be said about knowing what to expect coming out of the DB.

Of course, there's also something kind of elegant about building an ad-hoc object and saving it. At this point, node.js is very new and it's probably best to work with the stuff you like.

> Also the documentation is lacking, making some things I can easily do in the mongo shell harder then they should be.

Mongoose is still a community project and it's relatively new. If there are docs missing or needing to be written, I'm sure the development team would love the help. You can likely connect with them [on the groups](http://groups.google.com/group/mongoose-orm).

Answer (score 0):

I've used Mongoose and I have to say I totally agree that defining your Schema beforehand seriously limits MongoDB. The idea behind Mongoose was to make it safe and allows easy maintenance but doesn't really appeal for a document-based database.

Comment: I checked out mongoose pretty close to its release, and what this post and the op's post points out is that - you never really read the docs very well. Mongoose has always had the Mixed schema type for fields, which allows any and all data you would like to save ad-hoc available. In fact, if you so wish - you can make your collection behave in such a fashion, but it does severely hamper your application. If you need to check to see if data exists all the time, you don't really have any structure, which results in bugs, problems, and data inconsistencies.